# Limit of a recursive defined sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, limits

How can I calculate the limit in b) given the formula in a) when $a_0$ an $a_1$ are arbitrary? They gave us the tipp to find a similar form like the matrix-depiction in the introduction of the exercise but I do not see how I should work with that.

I was able to to it for $\alpha$ = $\sqrt 5$  by simply plugging it into the formula but this does not result in a general case where you can plug anything for $\alpha$ since then we could have for example $\infty$ - $\infty$.

Thanks for your help!

[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi38g.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:- First of all you were not asked to "plug in $\alpha$ " and show that it holds. You are asked to solve this recursive equation so that you end up with that formula. That is done by diagonalizing the matrix and computing the n-th powers . That yields the very famous Binet's formula

Now for the given system

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ \frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_{n-2} \\ a_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} a_{n-1}\\a_{n}\end{bmatrix}$$

Now diagonalize the matrix and compute the $n$-th powers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain what this has to do with the limit? I do not quiet understand it yet.

Comment: Check this out https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1157h990742_a_matrix_derivation_of_binets_formula . In my Linear Algebra class, we were given the task of deriving the Binet's formula using diagonalization. Apply the same to solve the recursion. Also you can look at how to solve linear recursion relations using auxiliary equation .